# I cannot access my Phys.SE account because I forgot my username/password. What to do?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

(Below follows the explicit case that spurred this meta question in the first place.)

I cannot access my account because I forgot my username, can you send me the email on my profile that is not public?

I contacted stack exchange several times because I had to make a duplicate account and I want to merge them. I have not still received any response after abunch of emails acros about a week.

Mt problem is that when I created my google account I misspelled it. I do remember the password, but not the username, and gogle doesnt help because I do not have an alternative email phone. 
The two accounts are for users: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/65081/wolphram-jonny, for which I have no longer access, and https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/65396/wolprhram-jonny, for which I do have login access. 
If you look at the history after the second account was created all activity from the first account stopped. Plus tte similarities in the answers and other caracteristics pose no doubt I am the same user.

Question: Is there any way to bring this to the attention of some moderator that can help me? I onlt need to know the mispelled username that is private in my profile. Once I have access to both account I will be able to ask for a standard merge, which require a confirmation email sent to both accounts.

**UPDATE**
The problem has been fixed now, thanks a lot!!!!! (the problem was apparently a backlog due to the holidays weekend)

Answer (score 3):

(I work for Stack Exchange)

Just [contact us directly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact) to handle this. Fixing it requires us asking you for additional information that needs to be given privately, so it's best handled via email. Give us up to 24 hours to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

The way to bring it to the attention of a moderator is to post here (or ping one of us in chat), but we can't help you in this way. Revealing personal information like this would be a violation of the moderator agreement. What we can do is bug the SE team to make sure they are working on your merge request, which I will go do right now.